# How to insert tags inside a input or textarea in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am going to design a textarea for writing some formula. Since typing entire formula may cause mistake in formula, I think its is better that users drag and drop variables from another panel. I believe that stackoverflow's tag option could be usefull for this purpose.
[image]

How it is possible to design a text area like this?

Comment: I tryed to insert disabled button inside text area. But it was not possible

Comment: you cant add any button in textarea you have to create a div and give it textarea nature..

Comment: Could you please provide a simple code as answer?

Comment: ok but before that confirm what nature exactly you want with textarea..

Comment: What do you mean by "nature"?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot directly convert the text box into tag. But you can make it look like a text box by giving a container to have the tag inside and a text box.

```
<div id="container"><span id="tagContainer"></span>
    <input type="text" id="inputText" placeholder="input here.." />
</div>
```

Using `keypress` event, you can grab the value of textbox and append it into `tagContainer`. You can see the implementation here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fztg615c/3/)

Comment: in this approach users can't remove tags

Comment: You can add that feature by yourself, please refer to my answer. If that plugin suits you, you can use that. Or else, you can develop by yourself as @Johan has suggested.

Comment: @Behnam you can use `click` event and use `remove` to remove the tags. Here is the implementation: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fztg615c/4/)

Comment: thanks for your help. also i need to math signs in my input. they are not tag.

Comment: @Behnam well, you can just give a checking for any of inputted text, if that is a math sign or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

However you can put another text block with highlight content at same position with that textarea or input.

Reference:

```
Visit https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR
```

Answer (score 0):

This plugin might be helpful for you. **http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/**