# How make a textarea with tags in react that have clickable dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Id like to make a component in react that allows me to have a textarea with tags that can be inserted when clicked from a dropdown. Id also like this textarea to be able to mix text aswell. I have currently been trying to use tagify with react but I cant seem to figure out a way to the tagify's function that adds the tag to be accessed by the onClick that is connected to the dropdown.

Any ideas?

[image]

---

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert tags inside a input or textarea in html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38119208/how-to-insert-tags-inside-a-input-or-textarea-in-html)

Comment: Have you got solution for this

Comment: I guess the direction will be set a `<div>` instead of a `<textarea>` and make it `contenteditable = true`. Once at this point, probably insert real HTML tags (probably `<span>`s that will give the proper shape to the text inside the span. Did you finally fins any categorical solution?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can get your answer in this URL of other question asked on StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/38119725/15405352

```js
var $container = $('.container');
var $backdrop = $('.backdrop');
var $highlights = $('.highlights');
var $textarea = $('textarea');
var $toggle = $('button');

// yeah, browser sniffing sucks, but there are browser-specific quirks to handle that are not a matter of feature detection
var ua = window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
var isIE = !!ua.match(/msie|trident\/7|edge/);
var isWinPhone = ua.indexOf('windows phone') !== -1;
var isIOS = !isWinPhone && !!ua.match(/ipad|iphone|ipod/);

function applyHighlights(text) {
  text = text
    .replace(/\n$/g, '\n\n')
    .replace(/[A-Z].*?\b/g, '<mark>$&</mark>');
  
  if (isIE) {
    // IE wraps whitespace differently in a div vs textarea, this fixes it
    text = text.replace(/ /g, ' <wbr>');
  }
  
  return text;
}

function handleInput() {
  var text = $textarea.val();
  var highlightedText = applyHighlights(text);
  $highlights.html(highlightedText);
}

function handleScroll() {
  var scrollTop = $textarea.scrollTop();
  $backdrop.scrollTop(scrollTop);
  
  var scrollLeft = $textarea.scrollLeft();
  $backdrop.scrollLeft(scrollLeft);  
}

function fixIOS() {
  // iOS adds 3px of (unremovable) padding to the left and right of a textarea, so adjust highlights div to match
  $highlights.css({
    'padding-left': '+=3px',
    'padding-right': '+=3px'
  });
}

function bindEvents() {
  $textarea.on({
    'input': handleInput,
    'scroll': handleScroll
  });

  $toggle.on('click', function() {
    $container.toggleClass('perspective');
  });  
}

if (isIOS) {
  fixIOS();
}

bindEvents();
handleInput();
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container, .backdrop, textarea {
  width: 460px;
  height: 180px;
}

.highlights, textarea {
  padding: 10px;
  font: 20px/28px 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

.backdrop {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  border: 2px solid #685972;
  background-color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.highlights {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    color: transparent;
}

textarea {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  margin: 0;
  border: 2px solid #74637f;
  border-radius: 0;
  color: #444;
  background-color: transparent;
  overflow: auto;
  resize: none;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

mark {
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: transparent;
  background-color: #b1d5e5;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 30px auto 0;
  padding: 10px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #74637f;
  font: 18px 'Opens Sans', sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  appearance: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.perspective .backdrop {
  transform:
    perspective(1500px)
    translateX(-125px)
    rotateY(45deg)
    scale(.9);
}

.perspective textarea {
  transform:
    perspective(1500px)
    translateX(155px)
    rotateY(45deg)
    scale(1.1);
}

textarea:focus, button:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #c6aada;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="highlights"></div>
  </div>
  <textarea>This demo shows how to highlight bits of text within a textarea. Alright, that's a lie. You can't actually render markup inside a textarea. However, you can fake it by carefully positioning a div behind the textarea and adding your highlight markup there. JavaScript takes care of syncing the content and scroll position from the textarea to the div, so everything lines up nicely. Hit the toggle button to peek behind the curtain. And feel free to edit this text. All capitalized words will be highlighted.</textarea>
</div>
<button>Toggle Perspective</button>
```

Reference- https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/gaLEMR for example

Comment: It's more of a comment than an answer. If you want to answer the question, copy-paste the relevant bits from the linked answer and explain how it resolves the issue.